# How do I get my location maps to appear in a loop using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I developed a loop of map locations using Carbon Fields for WordPress. The text of the display of the location and the structure of the maps is returned from the Google API, but the maps don't appear and there are no errors in the developer console. I hit a wall. What am I missing?

Before the loop starts I'm including the API

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY"></script>
```

I'm building out the locations loop in the php file with

I validated that all the values are correct when being passed to the function in my included scripts.js file.

The mapId is pulled from a data attribute in the map element.

```
<div id="map1" class="map" data-map="{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;42.6022909,-87.8485679&quot;,&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;42.6022909&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;-87.8485679&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;12&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;3203 Washington Road, Kenosha, WI&quot;,&quot;mapId&quot;:&quot;map1&quot;}">
```

I then loop through the map elements in jQuery and make sure the element is in the DOM before passing the element ID to the Google maps initMap function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('.map').each(function (index, Element) {
            let mapJsonData = jQuery(this).data("map");
            let mapId = this.id;
            let lng = mapJsonData.lng;
            let lat = mapJsonData.lat;
            let zoom = mapJsonData.zoom;
            console.log(mapJsonData);
            var thisMap = document.getElementById(mapId);
            console.log("mapId", mapId);
            if (thisMap) {
                initMap(mapId, lat, lng, zoom);
            }

        }); 

});
```

In the initMap function I again use document.getElementById(mapId) to ensure the element is in the DOM.

```
function initMap(mapId, lat, lng, zoom) {
    console.log("mapId initMap", mapId);
    var thisMap = document.getElementById(mapId);
    if (thisMap) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(thisMap, myOptions);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: parseFloat(zoom),
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            }
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        })
    }
}
```

I'm getting Google display code back when I view the source and there are no errors in the console and I made sure there was CSS included to give the map height.

```
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 328px;
}
```

Sample of locations data used to display the map

```
value: "43.1002943,-87.9535443"
lat: "43.1002943"
lng: "-87.9535443"
zoom: "12"
address: "3237 W. Glendale Avenue"
mapId: "map2"
```

Comment: This kind of error appears when Google Maps can't find the map element in the DOM, so probably here --> document.getElementById(mapId) . Check first what's in mapid, check if an element with that ID really exists, and if it does, check whether it is defined BEFORE the script runs.

Comment: Also, maybe it's just on the first callback method when you include the API script, since it doesn't have an ID parameter. Try removing this part from the URL: &callback=initMap

Comment: @Andrew I did try removing the callback and that didn't change anything. What you said about the problem being the first callback makes sense. I was seeing one empty result set in my testing. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the ID parameter.

I added the following to my jQuery each loop and now get no errors, but also no maps.
```
  let thisMap = document.getElementById(mapId);
  if (thisMap) {
   initMap(thisMap, lat, lng, zoom);
  }
```

Comment: What is `mapId`? Where is it defined?

Comment: mapId is pulled as JSON from a data field

<div id="map1" class="map" data-map="{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;42.6022909,-87.8485679&quot;,&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;42.6022909&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;-87.8485679&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;12&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;3203 Washington Road, Kenosha, WI&quot;,&quot;mapId&quot;:&quot;map1&quot;}">

Comment: I updated the original post with the most recent comments and code. There are no more errors and I added validation code, but I'm still not getting the maps.